# Way to change .jar return code and avoid SONAR violation "System.exit() should not be used in J2EE/JEE apps"

Tags: jar, sonarqube, system.exit

I have a JAR which will be scripted by others and requires custom return codes. I am using System.exit(int n) atm but SONAR complains giving a "Critical" violation.

> Do Not Call System Exit: System.exit() should not be used in J2EE/JEE
>   apps.

I believe SONAR will also complain about Runtime.exit().

Is there a way to override the JAR's return code and keep SONAR happy at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flag any issue as "False Positive" in the sonar IDE. The offending lines of code will be ignored in later sonar runs.

Furthermore you should add a comment, which describes why you flagged this.

[image: False Positive]

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was some other way to do this without changing the current SONAR rules, but this is still a valid fix.